# Why is this Haskell code so much slower than the C equivalent? Unboxed vectors and bangs already used

Tags: performance, haskell

I wrote a short Mandelbrot Set generator in Haskell and in C and discovered that the C version ran **20x** faster than the Haskell version. While I expected Haskell to be slower, I did not expect more than an order of magnitude considering I am already using unboxed vectors and bangs to avoid excessive thunking.

Profiling reveals that most of the time is spend in the the `go` function of the following code, which is really just a loop with some comparisons, multiplications and additions.

```
orbits limit radius a b = go 0 0 0
  where
    r2 = radius * radius
    go !n !x !y
      | n == limit    = n
      | x2 + y2 >= r2 = n
      | otherwise     = go (n + 1) (x2 - y2 + a) (2 * x * y + b)
      where
        x2 = x * x
        y2 = y * y
```

In execution, it takes the C code *0.9* seconds to run and it takes the equivalent Haskell code *18* seconds. They both implement the same algorithm and they both generate the same output (PGM graphics file).

The Haskell source code is here:

- [Main.hs](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5ff9bb4b9f074df99b3ac9e61175939a#file-main-hs)
- [MandelV.hs](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5ff9bb4b9f074df99b3ac9e61175939a#file-mandelv-hs)
- [mandel3.prof (profiling report)](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5ff9bb4b9f074df99b3ac9e61175939a#file-mandel3-prof)

The C code is here:

- [mandel.c](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5ff9bb4b9f074df99b3ac9e61175939a#file-mandel-c)

What could be the problem that causes this huge difference in performance?

Comment: What type are your numbers?

Comment: Try putting in a `orbits :: Int -> Double -> Double -> Double -> Int`

Comment: @Dan Yes, sorry, you've got the right type. I was experimenting. But even *with* all concrete types the Haskell version is still more than 7x slower. Why is this?

Comment: The next thing you want to look into is that `go` is doing 71% of the allocation. It's probably boxing and unboxing something in there. Make sure you're compiling with `-O2 -fllvm`, and try `-ddump-simpl` and heap profiling to see what's being allocated.

Comment: also maybe a good Idea is switching to unboxed types,

Comment: @epsilonhalbe While I want to find out why this is running slowly, I'd like to avoid unboxed types as it kills of a lot of the benefits of using Haskell in the first place.

Comment: Just adding the type signature to orbits like Dan said brought my time down from 17s to 4s.

Comment: @rityzmon: It's valid to not want to use unboxed types, but then you can't say your C and Haskell programs implement the same algorithm when C is using raw machine types and Haskell is using arbitrary-precision `Integers`

Comment: Are you sure you are adding `-O3` to the ghc compiler? This is a program you really want to optimize; with that, I'm down to 3x slowdown. The way you are doing the printing could also have some influence.

Comment: The Computer Language Benchmarks Game mandelbrot set generator C benchmark program is 2x faster than the Haskell benchmark program.

http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64q/performance.php?test=mandelbrot

Comment: Would 2x to 3x be a reasonable performance ratio between Haskell and C for numerical functions then?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### tl;dr - add type signature, use `ByteString` and turn on -O3

But first of all - as others have said before - you are not comparing the same things, while your c code uses a lot of mutability and the weak type system of c. And I believe also the writing to a file is more unsafe than the haskell equivalent. You have the benefit of type-checking/type-inference of haskell.

Also note that without any type signature your code is polymorphic - i.e. you could use the same code with `Float` or `Double`, `Word8` or `Int` if you desired to do so. Here lies the first trap - for integral numbers GHC defaults to `Integer`, an arbitrary precision integral number, equivalent to "bigint", which is usually slower by orders of magnitude.

Therefore adding a type signature, increases the speed tremendously.

(for exercise and learning) I did some comparison and implementation using unboxed types (ub-mandel), a typed version (mandel) and the op's untyped version (ut-mandel), as well as the c version (c-mandel).

measuring these programs you get the following (on a modern laptop using linux)

```
★ time ./c-mandel
./c-mandel  0,46s user 0,00s system 99% cpu 0,467 total

★ time stack exec -- ut-mandel
stack exec -- ut-mandel  9,33s user 0,09s system 99% cpu 9,432 total

★ time stack exec -- mandel
stack exec -- mandel  1,70s user 0,04s system 99% cpu 1,749 total

★ time stack exec -- ub-mandel
stack exec -- ub-mandel  1,25s user 0,08s system 98% cpu 1,343 total
```

Obviously the c code beats all implementations - but just adding the type signature brings a speedup by a factor of 5.49. Though doing the migration to unboxed types (which I have to admit was a first time) brings another 36 % speedup (note: this speedup is at the cost of the readability of the code).

But still this can be improved switching from the `String` version to `ByteString` gets us even further.

```
★ time stack exec -- ub-mandel-bytestring
stack exec -- ub-mandel-bytestring 0,84s user 0,04s system 98% cpu 0,890 total
```

### Lessons learned

- turn on type signatures
- turn on `-O3`
- use `Bytestring`
- if your code is still not fast enough - invest an hour and move to unboxed types
- if you still have energy, go read on reading llvm output and what the compiler does, a starting point would be [neil mitchell's blog article](https://neilmitchell.blogspot.co.at/2014/01/optimising-haskell-for-tight-inner-loop.html)

**Note:** all these calculations were done without the use of parallel computations, which I think could be done a lot more easily in haskell than in C. But this is a task I leave to someone else, or take a look at [gh: simonmar/parconc-examples](https://github.com/simonmar/parconc-examples/blob/master/mandel/mandel.hs) for a version that runs parallel on the gpu.

For completeness' sake the unboxed, bytestring version:

### `Main.hs`

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MagicHash #-}

module Main where

import Control.Monad
import Data.ByteString.Char8 as C
import System.IO (withFile, IOMode(WriteMode), Handle)

import           GHC.Prim
import           GHC.Exts (Int(..), Double(..))
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as U
import qualified MandelV as MV

savePgm :: Int -> Int -> Int -> U.Vector Int -> String -> IO ()
savePgm w h orbits v filename =
  withFile filename WriteMode $ \f -> do
    hPutStrLn f "P2"
    hPutStrLn f $ C.pack $ show w ++ " " ++ show h
    hPutStrLn f (C.pack $ show orbits)
    U.imapM_ (elm f) v
  where
      elm :: Handle -> Int -> Int -> IO ()
      elm f ix e =
          if rem ix w == 0
             then hPutStrLn f $ C.pack $ show e
             else hPutStr f $ C.pack $ show e ++ " "

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let w        = 2560#  :: Int#
      h        = 1600#  :: Int#
      x1       = -2.0## :: Double#
      y1       = -1.5## :: Double#
      x2       = 1.0##  :: Double#
      y2       = 1.5##  :: Double#
      filename = "test_hs.pgm"
      orbits   = 63#    :: Int#
      radius   = 2.0##  :: Double#

      v = MV.mandelbrot orbits radius x1 y1 x2 y2 w h :: U.Vector Int
  savePgm (I# w) (I# h) (I# orbits) v filename
```

### `MandelV.hs`

```
{-# LANGUAGE MagicHash #-}
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UnboxedTuples #-}

module MandelV where

import GHC.Prim
import GHC.Exts
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as U

orbits :: Int# -> Double# -> Double# -> Double# -> Int#
orbits limit radius a b =
    go 0# 0.0## 0.0##
  where
    r2 = radius *## radius
    go  ::  Int# -> Double# -> Double# -> Int#
    go !n !x !y
      | unsafeCoerce# (n ==# limit)       = n
      | unsafeCoerce# (x2 +## y2 >=## r2) = n
      | otherwise                         = go (n +# 1#) (x2 -## y2 +## a) (2.0## *## x *## y +## b)
      where
        x2 = x *## x
        y2 = y *## y

mandelbrot :: Int# -> Double# -> Double# -> Double# -> Double# -> Double# -> Int# -> Int# -> U.Vector Int
mandelbrot limit radius x1 y1 x2 y2 w h = U.generate (I# (w *# h)) f
  where
    mx = (x2 -## x1) /## int2Double# (w -# 1#)
    my = (y2 -## y1) /## int2Double# (h -# 1#)
    f :: Int -> Int
    f (I# ix) = I# (orbits limit radius x y)
      where (# j,i #) = quotRemInt# ix w
            x          = mx *## (x1 +## int2Double# i)
            y          = my *## (y1 +## int2Double# j)
```

relevant portions of

### `mandel.cabal`

```
executable ub-mandel
  main-is:             Main.hs
  other-modules:       MandelV
  -- other-extensions:    
  build-depends:       base >=4.8 && <4.9
               ,       vector >=0.11 && <0.12
               ,       ghc-prim
               ,       bytestring
  hs-source-dirs:      unboxed
  default-language:    Haskell2010
  ghc-options:         -O3
```

Comment: Great answer! It taught me how to use unboxed types!

Comment: This taught me much more about Haskell optimization than I knew before. Thanks.